# Kotest and kotlinx-coroutines-test Integration

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlintest, kotest

I use the Funspec testing style in kotest and I get a coroutineScope injected automatically by the framework as shown below.

```
class MyTestSpec: FunSpec() {
    init {
        test("test event loop") {
           mySuspendedFunction() // a coroutineScope is already injected by the test framework here     
        }
    }
}
```

How can I configure the Kotest framework to use an instance of `kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineScope` instead of a `kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope` in my tests? or is there a reason why this wouldn't make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a test listener like this:

```kotlin
class MainCoroutineListener(
    val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

) : TestListener {
    override suspend fun beforeSpec(spec: Spec) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override suspend fun afterSpec(spec: Spec) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
}
```

Then use it in your test like this

```kotlin
class MyTest : FunSpec({
    listeners(MainCoroutineListener())
    tests...
})
```

Comment: thanks any reason the dispatcher has to be reset after each spec? can't I leave it as it is as I want all the tests to use TestCoroutineScope instead of the normal one..

Comment: The listener will run before every spec so you only need to apply the listener once anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Since Kotest 5.0, there is built-in support for `TestCoroutineDispatcher`. See [here](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/coroutines/test-coroutine-dispatcher.html)

Simply:

```kotlin
class MyTest : FunSpec(
  {
    test("do your thing").config(testCoroutineDispatcher = true) { 
    }
  }
)
```